# select table name to select data from

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Hello (at start i wish to sorry for my bad english)

I have two tables: `tbl1` and `tbl2`; both have same structure but dataset in them if from different sources and i can't mix them.

in another table `tbl3` i have `dataid` and `datasource`.
what i wish to do is to select data from table linked in source.

pseudocode i try to produce:

```
SELECT
    tbl3.dataid,
    tbl3.datasource,
    SEL_TBL.important_data,
    SEL_TBL.another_thing,
    SEL_TBL.something_completly_different
FROM
    tbl3
LEFT JOIN
   ( SWITCH tbl3.datasource
        CASE  'tbl1':
           tbl1 AS  >> SEL_TBL
        CASE 'tbl2':
           tbl2 AS  >> SEL_TBL
   )
ON
    SEL_TBL.dataid = tbl3.dataid
```

i need result that contains: `important_data`, `another_thing` and of course `something_completly_different` from table selected in "switch statment".

what works right now :

```
SELECT 
    tbl3.dataid,
    tbl3.datasource,
   (
 CASE
    WHEN tbl3.datasource ='tbl1' 
    THEN
        tbl1.important_data
  ELSE
        tbl2.important_data
  END
   ) important_data
FROM
    tbl3
LEFT JOIN
    tbl2
ON
    tbl2.dataid = tbl3.dataid
LEFT JOIN
    tbl1
ON
    tbl1.dataid = tbl3.dataid
```

in results of this query i got `dataid`, `datasource` and `imporatn_data`. I can ofcourse repeat whole case block for every single field but perhaps there is more civilized method.

oh and one more thing: tbl1.dataid and tbl2.dataid can get the same value (that's why i can't mix tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to use a left join and include the join requirements.
Then coalesce gives you your results for each field.
Since this is a standard practice for star data models SQL optimizers will make it run quite fast.

```
SELECT 
    tbl3.dataid,
    tbl3.datasource,
    COALESCE(tbl1.important_data, tbl2.important_data)  important_data
    COALESCE(tbl1.another_thing, tbl2.another_thing) another_thing,
    COALESCE(tbl1.something_completly_different, tbl2.something_completly_different) something_completly_different
FROM tbl3
LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON  tbl2.dataid = tbl3.dataid AND tbl3.datasource = 'tbl2'
LEFT JOIN tbl1 ON  tbl1.dataid = tbl3.dataid AND tbl3.datasource = 'tbl1'
```

Comment: if i think correctly `COALESCE` will give me first NOT NULL value. in case when `datasource` is not given i get NULL. it's still a lot of code to write, but is more readable and should work as I exept. need/worth to try, thank you  :)